# Multiple references on one separate table-column possible?

Tags: sql, database-design, foreign-keys

Given is following database-structure:

**Products:**

```
- id
- model
- manufacturerID
- subcontractorID
```

manufacturerID and subcontractorID are referencing to one and the same table, because some manufacturers are also subcontractors:

**Manufacturers:**

```
- id
- name
```

Now, if I want to select both of these columns, how do I do that?

I tried something like this...

```
SELECT p.model, m.name AS Manufacturer, m.name AS Subcontractor
FROM Product AS p
LEFT JOIN Manufacturers AS m ON p.manufacturerID = m.id
LEFT JOIN m ON p.subcontractorID = m.id
```

... but I could only get one of both column-values.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Close - you need to join the Manufacturer table twice:

```
SELECT 
     p.model, manufacturer.name AS Manufacturer, 
     subcontractor.name AS Subcontractor
FROM Product AS p LEFT JOIN 
     Manufacturers AS manufacturer  
     ON p.manufacturerID = manufacturer.id LEFT JOIN 
     Manufacturers AS subcontractor 
     ON p.subcontractorID = subcontractor.id
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this one:

```
LEFT JOIN Manufacturers AS mman ON p.manufacturerID = mman.id
LEFT JOIN Manufacturers AS msub ON p.subcontractorID = msub.id
```